# MKStoreKit crash on iOS 7 with SIGTRAP error

Tags: ios, ios7, nsuserdefaults, storekit, mkstorekit

I have been over and over this live app crash log and cannot find the problem:

```
1    CoreFoundation  _CFHash + 130
2    CoreFoundation  CFBasicHashFindBucket + 724
3    CoreFoundation  _CFDictionaryGetValue + 99
4    CoreFoundation  -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSource setValue:forKey:] + 39
5    CoreFoundation  _CFXPreferencesSetValue + 139
6    CoreFoundation  _CFPreferencesSetAppValue + 45
7    Foundation  -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 61
8    MyApp   -[MKStoreManager rememberPurchaseOfProduct:withReceipt:] (MKStoreManager.m:884)
9    MyApp   -[MKStoreManager provideContent:forReceipt:hostedContent:] (MKStoreManager.m:848)
10   MyApp   -[MKStoreManager restoreTransaction:] (MKStoreManager.m:1004)
11   MyApp   -[MKStoreManager paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:] (MKStoreManager.m:911)
12   StoreKit    __NotifyObserverAboutChanges + 85
```

Here is the code that I believe is associated with the crash(es!):

```
- (void)rememberPurchaseOfProduct:(NSString*) productIdentifier withReceipt:(NSData*) receiptData {

    NSDictionary *allConsumables = [[MKStoreManager storeKitItems] objectForKey:@"Consumables"];
    if([[allConsumables allKeys] containsObject:productIdentifier])
    {
        NSDictionary *thisConsumableDict = [allConsumables objectForKey:productIdentifier];
        NSInteger quantityPurchased = [[thisConsumableDict objectForKey:@"Count"] integerValue];
        NSString* productPurchased = [thisConsumableDict objectForKey:@"Name"];

        NSInteger oldCount = [[MKStoreManager numberForKey:productPurchased] integerValue];
        NSInteger newCount = oldCount + quantityPurchased;

        [MKStoreManager setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:newCount] forKey:productPurchased];
    }
    else
    {
        [MKStoreManager setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:productIdentifier];

        //set flag in NSUserDefaults as another place we chan check to see if they have purchased the app
        //we may not want to check this, however, as an OR, since it can be easily jailbroken
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:productIdentifier];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    [MKStoreManager setObject:receiptData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-receipt", productIdentifier]];
}
```

I have been using this same code for years with no problem. Can anyone please help to point me in the right direction?

UPDATE: posting full crash log below

```
Incident Identifier: 07EF534E-E37C-4AF3-982A-11D6997A0D5C
CrashReporter Key:   CE01293A-021D-4DAD-BFA9-7F24957608B7
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,1
Process:         MyApp [1590]
Path:            /Users/USER/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      com.mysoftware.myapp
Version:         1.3.1
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-11-04T18:31:48Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 7.0.3 (11B511)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x2fdd01be
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2fdd01be _CFHash + 130
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2fdccb6c CFBasicHashFindBucket + 724
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2fdcc873 _CFDictionaryGetValue + 99
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2fe14ab3 -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSource setValue:forKey:] + 39
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2fe14a2f _CFXPreferencesSetValue + 139
5   CoreFoundation                      0x2fe14905 _CFPreferencesSetAppValue + 45
6   Foundation                          0x307d0a55 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 61
7   MyApp                         0x00134d59 -[MKStoreManager rememberPurchaseOfProduct:withReceipt:] (MKStoreManager.m:884)
8   MyApp                         0x0013496d -[MKStoreManager provideContent:forReceipt:hostedContent:] (MKStoreManager.m:848)
9   MyApp                         0x0013538f -[MKStoreManager restoreTransaction:] (MKStoreManager.m:1004)
10  MyApp                         0x00134ed5 -[MKStoreManager paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:] (MKStoreManager.m:911)
11  StoreKit                            0x325b6e85 __NotifyObserverAboutChanges + 85
12  CoreFoundation                      0x2fdd2ea1 _CFArrayApplyFunction + 37
13  StoreKit                            0x325b6e21 -[SKPaymentQueue _notifyObserversAboutChanges:sendUpdatedDownloads:] + 129
14  StoreKit                            0x325b76f9 -[SKPaymentQueue _processUpdates:trimUnmatched:sendUpdatedDownloads:] + 1017
15  StoreKit                            0x325b7dc9 -[SKPaymentQueue _setTransactionsWithReply:] + 129
16  StoreKit                            0x325b69bf __38-[SKPaymentQueue _establishConnection]_block_invoke_2 + 63
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a6e50c3 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a6e50af _dispatch_client_callout + 23
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a6e79a9 __dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 269
20  CoreFoundation                      0x2fe6a5b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
21  CoreFoundation                      0x2fe68e7d __CFRunLoopRun + 1309
22  CoreFoundation                      0x2fdd3471 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
23  CoreFoundation                      0x2fdd3253 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
24  GraphicsServices                    0x34b072eb _GSEventRunModal + 139
25  UIKit                               0x32688845 _UIApplicationMain + 1137
26  MyApp                         0x00083fff main (main.m:4)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a79d838 _kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a6e6623 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 39

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a79da84 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2fe6a559 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 157
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2fe68c79 __CFRunLoopRun + 793
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2fdd3471 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2fdd3253 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   WebCore                             0x37d9a0c5 RunWebThread(void*) + 421
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3a816c5d _pthread_body + 141
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3a816bcf __pthread_start + 103

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a79da84 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2fe6a559 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 157
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2fe68c79 __CFRunLoopRun + 793
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2fdd3471 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2fe170db _CFRunLoopRun + 99
5   CoreMotion                          0x3048b369 _CLSF_thorntonUpdate_6x6 + 57225
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3a816c5d _pthread_body + 141
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3a816bcf __pthread_start + 103

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a7b0c7c ___workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a7b0c7c ___workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a7b0c7c ___workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000     r1: 0x2fdd013d     r2: 0x00000000     r3: 0x00000304 
    r4: 0x00000000     r5: 0x00000004     r6: 0x00000000     r7: 0x004bb994 
    r8: 0x1752fd80     r9: 0x176e45a8    r10: 0x2ff063d0    r11: 0x3a9aa5c4 
    ip: 0x2fdd53c9     sp: 0x004bb98c     lr: 0x2fdccb6c     pc: 0x2fdd01be 
  cpsr: 0x60000030 

Binary Images:
   0x81000 -   0x202fff + MyApp armv7s  <fc1bc90151cf30da9de8889a1115ae51> /Users/USER/MyApp.app/MyApp
0x2eb73000 - 0x2eb8efff  libJapaneseConverter.dylib armv7s  <f248c9d2ab0c3a2c96b4afbb5f30e6f1> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libJapaneseConverter.dylib
0x2ed2f000 - 0x2ee30fff  AVFoundation armv7s  <759b362f09e53f37a2ec82372a95d1de> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x2ee31000 - 0x2ee59fff  libAVFAudio.dylib armv7s  <0925efab4dd338e382aa5b10cdbed33f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x2ee5a000 - 0x2ee5afff  Accelerate armv7s  <9340338f3cdf347abe4a88c2f59b5b12> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x2ee64000 - 0x2f031fff  vImage armv7s  <479b5c4701833284ab587a1d2fdb5627> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x2f032000 - 0x2f114fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <da4fa367557d3028b02458e2cdf6d84d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x2f115000 - 0x2f3d0fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <066ea8372dd23f6d89011f9a4a872d6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x2f3d1000 - 0x2f43ffff  libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <a5dcfe68199839b989c7be120c14ccb4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x2f440000 - 0x2f452fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <ea636bbda5ee33119a4e731aed02fa31> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x2f453000 - 0x2f453fff  vecLib armv7s  <663aefa25bc5367baa72ca144ac26d18> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x2f454000 - 0x2f473fff  Accounts armv7s  <811f7e5dcd353c57af6d6de859848774> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x2f474000 - 0x2f474fff  AdSupport armv7s  <fa30d96d0a333568826efd5aad83097a> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
0x2f475000 - 0x2f4dafff  AddressBook armv7s  <cc733c2c249e3161a9af19a44aeb1577> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x2f4db000 - 0x2f5ecfff  AddressBookUI armv7s  <8f681556d73d3ee5b9bfead2a124927c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x2f5ed000 - 0x2f5fefff  AssetsLibrary armv7s  <4c426c7f5e3930f0bd01d3e1f17f0392> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x2f743000 - 0x2fa5ffff  AudioToolbox armv7s  <f49f28790aa036c08e5573071a7e2870> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x2fa60000 - 0x2fb65fff  CFNetwork armv7s  <36562cff956f38a09956da9218198ccf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x2fb66000 - 0x2fbc1fff  CoreAudio armv7s  <34f47ad0c4d530249298888a1217316f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x2fbc2000 - 0x2fbd8fff  CoreBluetooth armv7s  <0211d5169d0d3838a9cbb9dd5086a312> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x2fbd9000 - 0x2fdcafff  CoreData armv7s  <4ed490c5fd693fefac89d75a47eab553> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x2fdcb000 - 0x2ff0efff  CoreFoundation armv7s  <37c6b3b7abca3774bec8fecf79f07013> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x2ff0f000 - 0x30033fff  CoreGraphics armv7s  <e13cbd4115dc3113b875de88b92744f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x30035000 - 0x30070fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7s  <4be02e4373903a7d8295e4e0859326ab>
```

(too long for SO to post the rest but I can add it in a comment if anyone thinks it could be helpful)

Comment: What is the actual error shown in the crash log? And which line is line 884?

Comment: Line 884 is: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:productIdentifier]; I am getting the crash report from a reporting service so I have a summary of the report that show "Reason: No reason string found. Exception Type: SIGTRAP"

Comment: Crashes are in iOS 7 only, primarily in 7.0.3 though it did happen once in 7.0.1; across all devices

Comment: Is it possible that `productIdentifier` is `nil`? Though I suppose that would cause problems earlier on. The `TRUE` should be `YES` but that wouldn't cause the crash.

Comment: Users have told me that they go through the process to purchase the app, then the content is not delivered; and that this is happening when they tap the restore button

Comment: could it have something to do with the observer?

Comment: @rmaddy any more thoughts on this? this particular piece of code has been working no problem since April, do you have any thoughts on what could have changed in iOS 7?

Comment: Without knowing the error I have no further ideas. I do know that iOS 7.0.3 is the first minor update to iOS that has broken one of my apps due to additional assertion checks.

Comment: I am showing my novice here but I am not really sure what assertion checks are. I wonder if they could be involved in this scenario? Is there a place where these changes are documented?

Comment: I added the (almost) full crash log. Can't find too much info for this error, especially in live apps. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Users purchase IAP, and nothing gets delivered, then they try to restore, and the app crashes, and every time since then they can't even launch the app.

Comment: I'm also seeing a similar issue. Would be very interested in hearing how you solve this.

Comment: I also have a similar issue - It's a lot worse given iOS7 even though the code works on my dev devices

Comment: @rmaddy you're right - apple IS returning a nil productIdentifier. So weird. see: https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/pull/176 for this exact issue.

Comment: Sorry, still working on it myself : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`productIdentifier` is `nil` as @rmaddy suggests in the comments. Other developers are reporting this issue on the `MKStoreKit` Github issues https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/pull/176

The suggested fix is here: https://github.com/dfabulich/MKStoreKit/commit/4b8adb442f1d7b7a9541feab5e319969369d3f95 by Dan Fabulich (not me).

In `MKStoreManager.m` `-(void) provideContent: (NSString*) productIdentifier` add a `nil` check at the top:

```
if (!productIdentifier) {
  NSLog(@"productIdentifier is nil; Apple bug?");
  return;
}
```